# Точка входа в приложение

Tags: delphi

Точка входа (адрес) главного файла (*exe)/модуля стороннего приложения, как узнать? Возможно ли это без инжекта?

Для лучшего понимания:
[image]

Comment: Не знаю, что это за инструмент, но `db 0F` наводит на мысль что встроенный дизассемблер не поддерживает некоторые инструкции)

Comment: Поглядел под идой, отображаются те же самые инструкции. Инструмент http://www.cheatengine.org/downloads.php
конечно, у него несколько иное предназначение, но мелких правок на ходу годится

Comment: Значит это не код, а данные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Формат исполняемых файлов PortableExecutables (PE)](http://emanual.ru/download/1298.html)

С самого начала экзешника идет MZ-заголовок, в котором можно найти смещение начала PE-заголовка. В PE заголовке есть поле 'Entry point RVA', это и есть адрес точка входа.

**UPD.** точнее, RVA - это относительный виртуальный адрес. Чтобы получить адрес точки входа, нужно к значению 'Entry point RVA' прибавить значение поля 'Image Base'.

**UPD.2** короче, как я понял, в вопросе под "точкой входа" подразумевается поле ImageBase, которое для экзешников как правило (возможно даже всегда) равно 0x400000. Каким образом экзешник может себя загрузить по какому-то "рандомному" адресу пока не понятно.

**UPD.3 и последний** WinXP не умела загружать экзешник по произвольному базовому адресу, Win7  - умеет (скорее всего Vista и Win8 тоже), при условии наличия в экзешнике таблицы релокаций. Т.о. нужно запускать программу и каким-то образом узнавать базовый адрес загрузки. Инжект или не инжект не могу сказать, т.к. с данной областью не знаком.

Comment: Простите за недостаток теоретической базы, что-то не выходит.
Экзешник, над которым произвожу экзекуции, открыл через PE Explorer, поглядел содержимое заголовка. Если я правильно понял, он мне показал:
Entry point RVA = 00522B19
Image Base = 00400000

Теперь, предположим, экзешник запущен. Мои действия?
Я лезу по адресу 00522B19, считываю из него dword, прибавляю Image Base и это будет точка входа? Но так ничего не выходит, потому что в запущенном приложении адреса 00522B19 нет.
Или же 00522B19+00400000? Но и такого адреса нет. Глупо себя чувствую.

Comment: У всех приложений, написанных на делфи, которые я открывал, точка входа главного модуля - 00400000. Exe, над которым мне требуется производить манипуляции, написан на C++ и такая точка входа каждый раз получается рандомной(

Comment: Скачайте [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/), посмотрите что он скажет. Entry Point не может быть рандомным - это именно то поле, по которому ось определяет откуда запускать экзешник.

Comment: Кстати, то что показано на рисунке - это не точка входа, а ImageBase+BaseOfCode

> Теперь, предположим, экзешник запущен. Мои действия? Я лезу по адресу 00522B19, считываю из него dword, прибавляю Image Base и это будет точка входа?

Нет, нужно открывать сам файл экзешника, а не лезть в память.

Comment: Просто смотрите какая задача. Я создаю процесс функцией CreateProcess, запуская некий чужой exe с флагом CREATE_SUSPENDED. Мне необходимо изменить условный переход на безусловный, грубо говоря, 1 байт подправить и потом я делаю ResumeThread. Для этого в процесс приходится инжектить DLL, а ведь было бы проще воспользоваться связкой VirtualProtectEx + WriteProcessMemory, чтобы лишнюю либу не таскать.
Этот 1 байт располагается в памяти процесса по адресу "файл.exe"+116D1, но адрес .exe в памяти всегда разный. У меня проблемы с терминологией( PEiD неизменно выдает "00122B19"

Comment: А патч до запуска не подходит? У меня другая проблема - я никогда не работал с уже запущенными процессами)

P.S. тут статейку нашел, может пригодится: [Создание загрузчика (loader) и патч в памяти](http://mimicria.ru/2009/05/06/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-loader-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8/)

P.P.S. А что за "чужая" программа, если не секрет?

Comment: До запуска не подходит, иначе бы не парился. Там очень сложная система защиты, в самом исполняемом файле проверок натыкано, сверка хэш суммы, автообновление и куча всяких примочек. Она игрушку запускает, общается с серверной частью защиты и не позволяет больше одного окна запустить; чтобы запускать несколько окошек - нужно платить абонентку или заходить с другого компьютера)
а я свою альтернативную запускалку пишу :)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял по вопросу, нужно это:

```
ExtractFilePath (Application.ExeName);
```

Извлечение полного пути (адреса) ехе"шника.

Comment: Упс, в слове Application сделал ошибку =(

Comment: Видимо, неправильно поняли. Смотрите, есть моё приложение, исполнительный файл Project1.exe.
Вот так я получаю точку входа (возможно выражаюсь не вполне корректно) главного исполнительного файла:

Form1.Caption:=IntToHex(dword(LoadLibrary(PAnsiChar(ExtractFileName(GetModuleName(0))))), 4);
не смущайтесь, я люблю многоэтажные вложенные функции..

Или так:
Form1.Caption:=IntToHex(dword(GetModuleHandle(nil)),4);

так вот - это в моём приложении. Не уверен, что это вообще хоть сколько-нибудь правильно, но выдает правильный адрес.
А если мне нужно то же самое узнать в приложении чужом?